# How to display an [object Object] on angular UI?

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to display the response of my backend api `http://localhost:3000/api/radar_life_cycle` on the angular UI but somehow I get the output as `[object Object]` ,console.log on the response shows the correct object but not on the UI,what am I missing?any guidance on how to display the object on UI?

html

```
<textarea rows="6" [(ngModel)]="enteredValue"></textarea>
<hr>
<button (click)="get_radar_lifecycle_data()">Search</button>
<p>{{newPost}}</p>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-radar-input',
  templateUrl: './radar-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./radar-input.component.css']
})


export class RadarInputComponent  {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
newPost = '';
get_radar_lifecycle_data(){
     this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/radar_life_cycle',{params:this.enteredValue}).subscribe(response => {
     console.log(response);
      this.newPost = response
      });
}

}
```

response:-

```
{message: "Posts fetched successfully!", posts: Array(1)}
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

[image]

Comment: Use this: `<p>{{newPost | json }}</p>` and check the value on UI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need inspect your object structure by `json pipe`

Display your object property by `ngFor` because result return `Array`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d17ggk

Comment: `{ "message": "Posts fetched successfully!", "posts": [ { "applicable_chipsets": [], "_id": "5d0c1f6284d47349138591a6", "Delivered": "N/A", "orgRadar": "51918661", "root_build": "", "inserted_by": "username", "milestone": "ms1", "project_tag": "", "inserted_on": "2019-06-20T17:05:54.896Z", "SDK": "" } ] }` is the object am trying to display, `<p *ngFor="let item of newPost.posts">{{item.posts.milestone}}</p>` doesn't display the milestone, why is that?

Comment: It is an item in array, you need use item.milestone

Comment: I keep getting error `ERROR in src/app/radar-input/radar-input.component.ts(19,78): error TS2339: Property 'enteredValue' does not exist on type 'RadarInputComponent'.` when compiling,any idea what  is missing?

Comment: You can declare enteredValue in your RadarInputComponent

Answer (score 6):

You can use the built-in JSON pipe that Angular has which is included in `@angular/common` and is imported with `BrowserModule` or `CommonModule`:

```html
<textarea rows="6" [(ngModel)]="enteredValue"></textarea>
<hr>
<button (click)="get_radar_lifecycle_data()">Search</button>
<p>{{newPost | json}}</p>
```

For more info about the pipe, check out the [`JsonPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) API.

Answer (score 1):

By referring `{message: "Posts fetched successfully!", posts: Array(1)}`!

You can use `*ngFor` to display the Array like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of newPost?.posts">
   {{ item.milestone }} 
</div>
```

or to display properties:

```
{{ newPost?.message }}
```

> Edit:

Change:

```
newPost = '';
```

to:

```
newPost: any;
```

and you already have access of object of that array so you just need to do:

```
{{ item.milestone }}
```

[`Working Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t2drda)

Comment: this throws errors `ERROR in src/app/radar-input/radar-input.component.ts(18,78): error TS2339: Property 'enteredValue' does not exist on type 'RadarInputComponent'.
    src/app/radar-input/radar-input.component.ts(20,12): error TS2339: Property 'newPost' does not exist on type 'RadarInputComponent'.`

Comment: @Flair Where and how did you declare `this.newPost`?

Comment: I updated the code declaring newPost, `{ "message": "Posts fetched successfully!", "posts": [ { "applicable_chipsets": [], "_id": "5d0c1f6284d47349138591a6", "Delivered": "N/A", "orgRadar": "51918661", "root_build": "", "inserted_by": "username", "milestone": "ms1", "project_tag": "", "inserted_on": "2019-06-20T17:05:54.896Z", "SDK": "" } ] }` is the object am trying to display, `<p *ngFor="let item of newPost.posts">{{item.posts.milestone}}</p>` doesn't display the milestone, why is that?

Comment: @Flair Change this: newPost = ''; to `newPost : any;`

Comment: @Flair and it should be `{{item.milestone}}` not `{{item.posts.milestone}}`